# Free action of a smooth variety is smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety and $G$ a finite group acting freely (i.e. $g.x=x\Rightarrow g=e$) on $X$, is the quotient $X/G$ a smooth algebraic variety again? I saw it be applied in e.g. page 171 of FGA explained.

It should be super obvious but I somehow failed to see it clearly.

Comment: It’s probably false as is (although I’m not sure). I suspect that the “natural” condition for a well-defined quotient  is that “every $G$-orbit is contained in some affine open subset”. Because then you can cover your variety with $G$-invariant affine open subsets, on which there is a well-defined quotient (the variety associated with the ring of $G$-invariants of the coordinate ring of these subsets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one extra piece of information here that's missing which is super important. By proposition 1.8 in SGA I, Exposé V, a necessary and sufficient condition for a quotient scheme $X/G$ to exist for a scheme $X$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $X$ is that the orbit of every point of $X$ be contained in an affine open subset. This is automatically satisfied if $X$ is quasi-projective, for instance.

Once you know that the quotient exists, it may be quickly concluded that $X/G$ is smooth as well: the quotient of a smooth manifold by a finite group acting freely is again a manifold, and since a variety over $\Bbb C$ is smooth iff it's complex points form a smooth manifold (and the complex points of the quotient are the quotient of the complex points), there you go. There are other arguments as well, depending on your level of sophistication.

Comment: Thank you, I think we can also argue by showing that the quotient morphism is smooth, can we?

Comment: I mean, you'd have to flesh that out a bit - it's not the case that a smooth map $X\to Y$ with smooth source must have smooth target.

Comment: I think we may do it in our case according to stack project [02K5], where we just take $S$ to be $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Sure, that works - I'm pretty sure I even used that in a paper a couple months ago, not sure why it didn't come to mind now.